# Scroll a stretched image

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have a picturebox in my c# windows forms application, and i've made some code so that I can alter the height and width of the picturebox, essentially zooming in. However, this only focuses on the top right area and I would like the user to be able to scroll the map to the area they need to using the scrollbar.

Whenever I zoom in, then use the scrollbar, my image goes to its default size, and then only scrolls in that size.

How can I move the entire image so that the user can pan the picturebox map?

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Mapping_Application
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Declare zoom variable counter
        int zoom;
        //Main Void
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Zoom In
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(zoom != 3)
            {
                pictureBox1.Height = pictureBox1.Height * 2;
                pictureBox1.Width = pictureBox1.Width * 2;
                zoom = zoom + 1;
            }            
        }

        //Zoom out
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (zoom != 0)
            {
                pictureBox1.Height = pictureBox1.Height / 2;
                pictureBox1.Width = pictureBox1.Width / 2;
                zoom = zoom -= 1;
            }
        }

        //The horizontal scrollbar
        private void horizontal_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            //Create a graphics object and draw a portion of the image in the PictureBox.
            Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

            int x;
            int y;

            if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll)
            {
                x = e.NewValue * 19;
                y = vertical.Value * 19;
            }
            else //e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll
            {
                y = e.NewValue * 19;
                x = horizontal.Value * 19;
            }

            g.Clear(Color.White);

            g.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image,
              new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Width),  //where to draw the image
              new Rectangle(x, y, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Width),  //the portion of the image to draw
              GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            pictureBox1.Update();
        }

        //The vertical scrollbar
        private void vertical_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            //Create a graphics object and draw a portion of the image in the PictureBox.
            Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

            int x;
            int y;

            if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll)
            {
                x = e.NewValue * 19;
                y = vertical.Value * 19;
            }
            else //e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll
            {
                y = e.NewValue * 19;
                x = horizontal.Value * 19;
            }

            g.Clear(Color.White);

            g.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image,
              new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Width),  //where to draw the image
              new Rectangle(x, y, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Width),  //the 
portion of the image to draw
              GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            pictureBox1.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

The scroll currently seems to work, but for no zoom in only. There is no zoom negative feature and i'm using a var named zoom to store which level zoom the program is at. Can't zoom to -2x , hence the if (zoom!=0)

Comment: Set the pbox to to zoom; nest it in a Panel. set the panel to autoscroll. to zoom in or out make the pbox larger or smaller

Comment: Okay, i'll give this a try. Thanks.

Comment: @TaW This worked. Thanks.